# User Stories before or during Iteration Planning

Tags: agile, scrum, user-stories

We are just beginning to move from Waterfall to Agile.  One of the few complaints about our new process is that our iteration planning meetings are taking too long, mostly because we are writing our story cards in the meeting itself, which was how the process was described to me.

One suggestion was that we write the story cards ahead of the meeting and ask everyone to review them before they come to the meeting as a potential time saver.

Is there an advantage to doing the stories during the meeting, vs. writing the story cards ahead of time and asking people to review them ahead of time, potentially saving everyone some time?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming.

Answer (score 3):

This is probably not an ideal question to ask as there's no real definitive answer. Responses are likely to be subjective.

Relating to my own experience, our team tends to get Stakeholders and Product Owners to add User stories in an adhoc fashion during our sprints to a projects product backlog (we work on a web application and are user driven in terms of functionality - we do have a roadmap, but we also adapt to feedback etc).

That way, when it comes time to do iteration planning we have a brief Product planning meeting with Stakeholders, Product Owner and project leads to discuss priority and adjust User Stories on our product backlog.

Once that's done, there's a subsequent Sprint Planning session with project teams that pluck off User Stories to work on in the sprint (picking off enough User Stories that we feel can be realistically achieved when gauged against our established velocity).

I'm sure other people do it differently, the key thing is to find something that works for you and your team.

Comment: I would agree that you'll find many answers.  Scrum in particular is a framework within which you discover the right process.  It is a good rule of thumb that you should feel prepared for Sprint planning by sustaining a rolling backlog of greater down to less understood items.  It sounds like you're seeing a signal around this and should look to experiment with your process.

Answer (score 1):

> which was how the process was described to me

You identified a problem in your process (too long planning meeting) and found out the root cause for it (writing story cards). The most sensible and agile thing to do is probably not to stick to "how the process was described" but to adapt accordingly, which means creating the cards in advance.

That said, from my personal experience, the sooner user stories are presented by the Product Owner to the team the better. Sprint Planning will probably be when story estimates are refined and little details are tackled, but it's generally better if the team did at least some exploration and estimation ahead and don't arrive at the meeting completely ignorant.

Answer (score 0):

One of the most important purposes of User Stories is to serve as a conversation starter among developers and stakeholders. Based on my experience, it can save a lot of time to have one or two people review all of the existing requirements or requests and translate them into user stories.

But it is vital that the story cards get discussed, and that *should* take considerable time. Even though it seems like a lot of time that could be better spent on development, the reality is that, without discussion, development can easily go in the wrong direction. Asking people to review the cards ahead of the meeting often does not work - if they don't want to take time to discuss the cards during the meeting, they probably won't review the cards on their own time.

My advice: ask two people to work together on writing the user stories ahead of the meeting, but use the meeting to review and discuss each card.